# Converting gzip files to bzip2 efficiently

Tags: conversion, gzip

I have a bunch of gzip files that I have to convert to bzip2 every now and then. Currently, I'm using a shell script that simply 'gunzip's each file and then 'bzip2's it. Though this works, it takes a *lot* of time to complete.

Is it possible to make this process more efficient? I'm ready to take a dive and look into gunzip and bzip2's source codes if necessary, but I just want to be sure of the payoff. Is there any hope of improving the efficiency of the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was asked a long time ago when [pbzip2](https://launchpad.net/pbzip2) either wasn't available or wasn't capable of compressing from stdin, but you can now parallelize both uncompressing and compressing steps using [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and [pbzip2](https://launchpad.net/pbzip2) (instead of [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/)):

```
ls *.gz | parallel "gunzip -c {} | pbzip2 -c > {.}.bz2"
```

which is significantly faster than using [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/).

Comment: Hi, I've changed the accepted answer to this one since this gives the best option for people stumbling upon the question today. Thanks for the `pbzip2` mention. In case the link doesn't load for anyone else, here's the [project page](https://launchpad.net/pbzip2) and the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pbzip2).

Answer (score 16):

Rather than gunzip in one step and bzip2 in another, I wonder if it would perhaps be more efficient to use pipes.  Something like `gunzip --to-stdout foo.gz | bzip2 > foo.bz2`

I'm thinking with two or more CPUs, this would definitely be faster.  But perhaps even with only a single core.  I shamefully admit to not having tried this out, though.

Comment: +1 for piping, disk I/O is something you want to avoid. As for compression, unless I'm mistaking, bzip2 isn't parallell. You'd have to use something like pbzip2 to compress in parallell: http://compression.ca/pbzip2/

Comment: ... and unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any parallell gzip decompression utility available.

Comment: @gustafc: Thanks for the link to pbzip2, that was very helpful... 
@OP: I shied away from piping bcos I want to be able to deal with corrupt gz files, etc., without losing them in the pipe...

Comment: @gustafc: Even if `bzip2` and `gzip` don't work in parallel internally, by using a pipe you can have them work in parallel, because a pipe implicitly starts two processes, which *will* run in parallel. So at least decompression and compression will run in parallel.

Comment: @sleske, even though you are right in theory, `bzip2`'s CPU usage dwarfs the `gunzip` one, so in practice the parallelism you get here is minimal. Not having to do disk IO is still nice though!

Comment: @JohanWalles: Yes, but that is _precisely_ why the parallelization made possible by the pipe is useful: If you instead decompress first to file, then bzip2, you a) incur extra I/O (as mentioned), and b) the CPU cannot even start working on the bzip2 compression before gunzip is done. The fact that gunzip takes little CPU is one more reason to let bzip2 run in parallel, because there's lots of idle CPU to use.

Answer (score 7):

GNU parallel (http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel) might be an option if you have multiple cores (or even multiple machines):

```
ls *.gz | parallel "gunzip -c {} | bzip2 > {.}.bz2"
```

Read the tutorial / man page for details and options.

Answer (score 3):

What you're currently doing is your best bet. There is no conversion tool available, and attempting to bzip2 an already gzipped file is not really an option, as it frequently has undesired effects. Since the algorithm is different, converting would involve retrieving the original data regardless. Unless of course gzipping was a step in the bzip2 process, in which it isn't unfortunately.

Comment: Don't the algorithms have _any_ overlapping steps such that I could skip one step in gzip decompression and the same in bzip compression also?

Comment: @sundar I wouldn't think so. `gzip` uses Leimpel-Ziv 77, while `bzip2` uses Burrows-Wheeler. Different algorithms, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally, I need to do the same thing with log files. I start with the smallest *.gz files first (`ls -rS`), gunzip and then and bzip2 them individually. I do not know if it is possible to direct the gunzip output directly to the bzip2 input. The bzip2 command is so much slower at compressing than gunzip is at decompression that it may consume the memory and swap space on the host.

Improvements or suggestions are welcome. Here is my one liner:

```
for i in $(ls -rS *.gz | sed 's/\.gz//'); do gunzip ${i}.gz; bzip2 -9 ${i}; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, the point about the difference in speed between the two processes and its implication is an important one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than a few, check out the LJ article with a nice shell script.

http://linuxgazette.net/123/bechtel.html

7zip gets better compression, and is multi threaded.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to do this a few minutes ago:

```
find . -name "*.gz" | perl -pi -e 's/\.gz$//g;' | xargs -n1 ./rezip
```

Where `rezip` would be defined as:

```
#!/bin/bash
gunzip -v $1.gz && bzip2 -9v $1
```

Optionally, you can also make it multi-threaded by using a `-P` option with `xargs`, but be careful with that one.  (Start low!)